# Looping through all active Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a really weak experience working with VBA, but now faced an issue where it is really required.

I need to copy cell's value from multiple worksheets (besides "Summary") into one worksheet, but facing a problem. When running a macro, I get around 30 lines with the values I need, but all 30 values belong to the same worksheet. Seems like the loop is running only around 1 worksheet. Could you help me finding the mistake in the code?

```
Sub CopyTotalSalesPrice()

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Worksheet.Name <> "Summary" Then

Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Select
End If
    If Selection.Value > "0" Then
       Selection.Copy
       Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

       Range("D4").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

Next Worksheet

Worksheets("Summary").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Select and everything else, they refer to the current sheet. So you either put in front of them Worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Select or you activate the sheet first with Worksheet.Activate

or you can just do as follow:

```
Sub CopyTotalSalesPrice()
    For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Worksheet
            If .Name <> "Summary" Then
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
                .Range("D4").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
            End If
        End With
    Next Worksheet
    Worksheets("Summary").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Tried WorkSheet.Cells, but it gave a mistake "Select Method or Range Class Failed", but activation of the worksheet made exactly what I needed! :) Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyTotalSalesPrice()

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Worksheet.Name <> "Summary" Then
      Worksheet.Select
      Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Select
    End If
    If Selection.Value > "0" Then
      Selection.Copy
      Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

      Range("D4").Select
      Selection.Copy
      Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

Next Worksheet

Worksheets("Summary").Select
End Sub
```

I replaced this `Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Select` with `Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Select`

Comment: Thank you for your response. As Gotrekk suggested this above, I decided to simply copy your code, but I still get "Select Method or Range Class Failed". Do you have any idea why this problem might appear? Since both of you suggested this option, it is definitely something wrong on my side?!

Comment: edit your question with the new code... we will have a look

Comment: changed it to Worksheet.Cells solution.

Comment: you still need to Worksheet.Activate or Worksheet.Select before the Worksheet.Cells(Worksheet.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Select

Comment: i changed my answer with another option to do the same thing